# Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysqli

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /public_html/header.php on line 35

In the header.php,
Connect to database:

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","$db_name","$password")
$sql_logo="SELECT * FROM `logo`";
$query_logo=mysqli_query($connect,$sql_logo);
```

On line 35:

```
<?php 
   while($result=mysqli_fetch_object($query_logo)){
?>
   <a href="/"><img src="res/img/<?php echo $result->logo_img?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

in my database:
the table name is `logo` and the column name is `logo_img`.

I don't know what happens, because when I try in XAMPP it's work using that's code.

Comment: Check the return value from `$query_logo`. If it's false - as it almost certainly is - check `mysqli_error($connect)` to see why your query failed.

Comment: you didn't select a db and didn't close off `("localhost","$db_name","$password")` < missing `;`

Comment: thanks, the error is not select db.
i have try `$mysqli_connect("localhost","$user","$db_name","$password")`
but i wrong to put the `db_name`, i must put `db_name` after `password` not before it.

Comment: @MuhamadSofyan the parameters order is wrong as stated in my answer below.

Comment: @deceze the question you used as a dupe source is related to obsoleted extension while answers there promote outdated and harmful practices. Please consider using the answer I wrote for the purpose instead: [mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param/22662582#22662582)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","$db_name","$password")`

2 things here.

The `$db_name`, that must be the last parameter and you've a missing closing semi-colon.

The syntax is:

- host
- username
- password (if any)
- database

As per the manual

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Make sure you also did properly assign those variables.

If there's no password, you still need the parameter for it, but as empty.

I.e.:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "", "my_db");
                                                ^ that is for the password parameter
```

Check for errors also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: yeah i wrong put `db_name`, i put it before `password` so i find that's error, because the `db_name` must put after `password`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$query_logo` is probably `FALSE` instead of the results you're trying to fetch. This could mean either your `mysqli_connect`fails, or the `$sql_logo` query fails.

Print the errors out using `echo mysqli_error($connect)` and you will find your answer there.

Also, I'd recommend having a look at object oriented mysqli, looks like you're still figuring stuff out, don't get used to procedural or you'll regret it later.

Comment: Why the recommendation to avoid procedural based mysqli?

Comment: @andrewsi personal opinion

Comment: Ah, that's fair enough then :)

Answer (score -2):

Please refer the PHP-Manual
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
 for getting the better idea of mysqli syntax.

And for displaying records try to use syntax and code given below:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "db_username", "db_password", "Database_anme");
$limit = 10; //$_POST['limit'];
$start   = 0; //$_POST['start'];
$r = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` DESC LIMIT $start,$limit");
while($quotos = mysqli_fetch_object($r)){
    // Your code goes here
}
```